# How do I do a regex string substitution using a Regex with backreferences in Rust?

Tags: regex, replace, rust

I'm trying the following code, but, which works for other languages, but not for Rust

```
#[test]
fn regex_test() {
    let regex = Regex::new(r"(\*|_)(.*?)\1").unwrap();
    let string = "*quack* klfjalksd *this* is a *test* **dfadfjkl** ";
    let substitution = "<em>$2</em>";

    // result will be a String with the substituted value
    let result = regex.replace_all(string, substitution);

    println!("{}", result);

}
```

The result has none of the substitutions:

```
*quack* klfjalksd *this* is a *test* **dfadfjkl**
```

Comment: Have you found any solution? I have been searching for this

Comment: None, I've just had to refactor my code to not use backreferences.

Comment: I ended up using fancy-regex, BTW

Answer (score 7):

From the [`regex` crate documentation](https://docs.rs/regex):

> This crate provides a library for parsing, compiling, and executing regular expressions. Its syntax is similar to Perl-style regular expressions, but **lacks a few features like look around and backreferences**. In exchange, all searches execute in linear time with respect to the size of the regular expression and search text.

Your regex uses backreferences. If you want to use backreferences in Rust, then I'd recommend [`fancy-regex`](https://docs.rs/fancy-regex) or some other crate that binds to another regex engine such as PCRE or Oniguruma.

In this case (for `regex 0.2.x`), `\1` is interpreted as an octal escape, which corresponds to the Unicode codepoint `U+0001`.

Comment: So far I've tried fancy-regex, and onig, and they can't do this either, or if they can the syntax for the substitution is undocumented.

Comment: You might need to implement substitution yourself, but they both support backreferences, which is the fundamental problem you're hitting.